# MultipleChoiceField django python, impossible display datas in the template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have big problem, I use MultipleChoic Field into django for "input multiselect",
a user at the possibility of make many choices via the "input select multiple"

I explain to you :

I use this Package : https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/

this is my model :

```
class Profil(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,) 
skill = MultiSelectField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, choices=Skillz)
board = MultiSelectField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, choices=Boardz)
```

this is my form :

```
class ProfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
skill = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=Skillz)
board = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=Boardz)
```

this is my datas of the choices (used in models Profil and form ProfilForm):

```
Boardz = (
('Reddit', 'reddit.com'),
('Discord', 'discord.com'),
('Twitter', 'twitter.com'),
)

Skillz = (
('Python', 'PythonDjango'),
('Rust', 'RustRocket'),
('Ruby', 'RubyOnRails'),
)
```

Now the concern problem is views.py and my template.html

```html
<!-- this is what I want with my datas -->
<select multiple class="form-control" id="id_board">
     <option>reddit.com</option> 
     <option>discord.com</option>
     <option>twitter.com</option>
 </select>

<select multiple class="form-control" id="id_skillz">
     <option>PythonDjango</option>
     <option>RustRocket</option>
     <option>RubyOnRails</option>
 </select>
 
 <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Into the views.py (which is surely wrong) :

```
def GetDatasForRegisterForm(request):
form = ProfilForm()
return render_response(request, "registration/register.html",{'form': form})
```

template.html : 
I'm totally lost for display my data choices in select multiple for the user, please guys, how make ?

Answer (score 1):

Update : It's good, I have what I wanted, here is for your members of stack overflow, my solution :

```
class ProfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
 skill = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=Skillz) # skillz and boardz into choices.py 
 board = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=Boardz)

 class Meta:
    model = Profil
    fields = ('skill', 'board',)
```

in views.py > form = ProfilForm(), return render..

```
{% for value,text in form.board.field.choices %}
 <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i go about generating my template and views.py when dealing with forms.

First here you have defined your form `ProfilForm` one quick way to know the html generated in your form when your views look like

```
def GetDatasForRegisterForm(request):
    form = ProfilForm()
    return render_response(request, "registration/register.html",{'form': form})
```

In your templates you can just do

```
<form method="POST" action="<your_action>">
{{ csrf_token }}
{{ form.as_p }}

 <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Now when you render this django will create a basic HTML for you, based on model specified. You can copy the HTML and customize the styling and populate the values by accessing the form field values.

Now you haven't asked about how to save this form. But let me do that anyway.

We are going to handle the form post in the same controller which will look like.

```
def GetDatasForRegisterForm(request):
    form = ProfilForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return redirect("/<sucess_page>")
    return render_response(request, "registration/register.html",{'form': form})
```

In the view here, i am loading the form with POST data if it exists and checking if the form is valid in the POST and saving it as well. You can where to lead the page to if it is success or error.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, {{ form.as_p }} does not work, and it's not p tags that I want, but a multiple selection like the example above.
For saving data, it is important to know that at the same time I save data in the User model (username, email ..). And my "multiple select" in the Profil  that extends from User.
I wish above all to succeed in recovering my data "choices" so that the user can select things

Comment: form.as_p should render the html for your form fields. That should help to get the html tag. This is just to know the structure.

Comment: Yes, alas, it does not work, I have no display, I confess that I find it really weird, it's been 20 hours that I'm struggling on this type of form.
I have in views.py a function, in the function there is a code that calls the ProfilForm form, then I send it to the page.html, I use the famous {{form.as_p}}, but that does not not work ^^  please look https://pastebin.com/a9s2mnaY

Comment: Ok, after a long battle, I managed to display my forms "select multiple" with my data, unfortunately it's really ugly when you get the forms with {{form.as_p}} I can not stylize with bootstrap. . https://pastebin.com/4yXegFgh ^^