# Based on model multiselectfield show result in template django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, multi-select, modelform

based on multiple choice field i want to show result in template but I have no idea how to do as you can see in this model i give lunch choice to students base on lunch choice i want to show result but it is not working for ex if he select sandwich the result after submit will you sandwich will be ready and same for others

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
class student(models.Model):
    lunch_choice = [ 
        ('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'),
        ('Salad', 'Salad'),
        ('omlete', 'omlete'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
    classs =  models.CharField(max_length70, blank=True)
    lunch =  MultiSelectField(choices=lunch_choice, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i tried in my HTML and it didn't work

```
{% if student.classs %}
{% if student.lunch == 'Sandwich' %}
          <p> your sandwich will be ready</p>
{% endif %} 
{%endif%}
```

and in form.py using widget

```
widgets = {
    'lunch':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id':'lunch'}),
}
```

my views.py

```
def preview(request):
    student = student.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'preview.html',{'student':student})
```

Comment: `{% if student.lunch == 'Sandwich' %}`

Comment: when I use charfied in place of multi-select field it worked but it does not allow me to select more than one option and If I select more than one then the form does not save

Comment: so i have to use multi-select field in order to achieve that

Comment: @Blackranger the algorithm is the same as in the previous question, only you need to display the data on the page?

Comment: yes dependin on what option he seleys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acc to me there is no such way by which u can show the result base on selected option because i also tried to use that and look for answers on internet but didn't find anything and creator of that repo is also not responding although I would recommend you to use models many to many field It will allow user to select more than one option like multiselectfield like this

first, create models

```
class Lunch(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

then add this in student models

```
lunch =  models.ManyToManyField(Lunch, blank=True, related_name="lunch")
```

then add your option in lunch model

and it in your template to show result base on selected option

```
{% if student.classs %}
{% for Lunch in student.lunch.all %}
{% if Lunch.title == 'Sandwich' %}
          <p> your sandwich will be ready</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %} 
{%endif%}
```

it will work

Answer (score 3):

OP can create a model for lunches (it would enable to create new lunches, edit and delete). Then, in the Student model create a lunch with a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), like

```
lunch = models.ManyToManyField(Lunch, blank=True)
```

Note the usage of `blank=True` to not require the field in the forms.

Then, when one generates a form based on that model, it'll create an experience just like the one in Django Admin where one can select multiple ones.

[One can then show it to the user in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270472/7109869).

---

If one doesn't like the experience of the form and want to make it more user friendly, there are some articles out there explaining that

- [Django Forms for Many-to-Many Fields](https://medium.com/swlh/django-forms-for-many-to-many-fields-d977dec4b024)
- [How To Add Tags To Your Blog (A Django ManyToManyField Example)](https://ctrlzblog.com/how-to-add-tags-to-your-blog-a-django-manytomanyfield-example/)

Comment: but I am looking for a way to show results on the basis selected option

Comment: @Blackranger Does that mean without having that saved in the database first? If not, the link in "One can then show it to the user in a template" will work.

Comment: the data is already saved in the model now I retrieving the information from it if user is selected sandwich lunch  show  result but this tag is not working   {% if student.lunch == 'Sandwich' %}

Comment: If the goal is to edit or add a different lunch or delete, the way OP is doing isn't the most correct - hence the `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: And it's definitely a workaround to solve that problem. 
Unless OP really wants to fix that particular one, in which case just did some research and couldn't find any good examples but found other people with the same problem

Comment: Maybe going through [this road](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115027/5675325), but the type of field appears to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the string is being compared to type: type(aaa[0].lunch) <class 'multiselectfield.db.fields.MSFList'>. Printed the data type 'type(aaa[0].lunch)' of the first value from the database in the view. Used stringformat:'s' to convert data to string in template. Here you can read about the conversion:
[conversion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat)

transformation [type:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

**replace 'samplesite' with the name of your application.**

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("Test/", Test, name = 'Test'),
]
```

views.py

```
def Test(request):
    aaa = student.objects.all()
    print('type(aaa[0].lunch)', type(aaa[0].lunch))
    context = {'fff': aaa}

    return render(request, 'samplesite/lunch.html', context)
```

lunch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    {% for aa in fff %}
    {% if  aa.lunch|stringformat:'s' == 'Sandwich' %}
    <p>{{aa.lunch}}</p>
    <p>{{aa.name}}</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
```

django version 4.1
[image]

Comment: it did not work at still loading empty

Comment: do you have the data in the database itself?

Comment: yes i do have the data

Comment: using default database db.sqlite

Comment: I uploaded a gif showing how the data looks in the database and how it is displayed on the page. You can try to do what i have: lunch = MultiSelectField(choices=lunch_choice, null=True, blank=True, max_choices=3, max_length=30)

Comment: i tried but not working still can please upload it on GitHub so I can see it

Comment: @Blackranger posted the project(sample.rar) [here](https://github.com/quant12345/Machine-learning-and-graphics-for-financial-markets-and-beyond)
The data is already in the database. To start it: http://localhost:8000/book/Test/